# Having problems running shellinabox on my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shell, ubuntu, web, ssh

I have been trying to use shellinabox. I cloned the github repo below and followed the steps mentioned.

https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox

My /etc/default/shellinabox file is like below:-

```
# Should shellinaboxd start automatically
SHELLINABOX_DAEMON_START=1

# TCP port that shellinboxd's webserver listens on
SHELLINABOX_PORT=4200

# Parameters that are managed by the system and usually should not need
# changing:
# SHELLINABOX_DATADIR=/var/lib/shellinabox
# SHELLINABOX_USER=shellinabox
# SHELLINABOX_GROUP=shellinabox

# Any optional arguments (e.g. extra service definitions).  Make sure
# that that argument is quoted.
SHELLINABOX_ARGS="--o-beep"
```

All steps were same for me except the deb package installation which I downloaded from a resource which is shellinabox_2.20_armel.deb which i kept in the root folder.

**On the other hand I tried all steps in below link too :-**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/414930/access-webpage-through-ssh

**and have watched the below video from youtube:-**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2viORNwxNTY

But I am not able to run the localhost using my IP address to access it. https://myipaddress:4200/

When I try to access the url in web browser I see

> This site can’t be reached.
>
> myipaddress refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: For `myipaddress` to work, your public IP address needs to be configured to accept connections to port 4200 from the whole wide world. This is probably not a good idea, and your firewall probably blocks it. If you just want it to work locally, try http://127.0.0.1:4200/ (127.0.0.1 is your local loopback, i.e. the network driver just connects back to your own computer without actually connecting to the network).

Comment: @tripleee Thanks it worked.

Comment: @tripleee but I am unable to log in and its showing me session closed when i type my username. Can u help me with that too ?

Comment: Nope, no experience with this particular project, and doesn't seem to be a programming question anyway.

Comment: @tripleee Ok. Thanks.